# Filling an array in a component with JSON objects Angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I am trying to access keys and values in a JSON response to fill an array. This array is currently blank and is used for chart.js. The API: https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json has keys and values that are changing every 24 hours, i.e.:

```
{"bpi":
  {"2017-10-06":4370.245,
  "2017-10-07":4437.0338,
  }
}
```

**The array 'data' needs to be filled inside the component.ts file, and not in a template or .html file**

```
chartData = [
    { data: [], label: 'Bitcoin' },
  ];
```

To clarify, I am trying to fill the array 'data' with values such as '4370.245' which are coming from an http.get request from the above url.

Comment: Here's how to access it: `chartData[0].data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
chartData = [
    { data: [], label: 'Bitcoin' },
  ];

let arrayData = chartData[0].data;//this will return you data inside chartData
```

**Edited as per coomment**

```
    var outputData = []

    var keysArray = Object.keys(tmpObj.bpi)
    for (var key in tmpObj.bpi) {
        if (tmpObj.bpi.hasOwnProperty(key )) {
            outputData.push(tmpObj.bpi[key])
        }
    }
    console.log(outputData);
```

```js
var tmpObj = {"bpi":
  {"2017-10-06":4370.245,
  "2017-10-07":4437.0338,
  }
};

var outputData = []

var keysArray = Object.keys(tmpObj.bpi)
for (var key in tmpObj.bpi) {
if (tmpObj.bpi.hasOwnProperty(key )) {
 outputData.push(tmpObj.bpi[key])
}
}
console.log(outputData);
```

Comment: How can I add content from the API to this array?

Comment: `chartData[0].data = API_RESPONSE;`

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal thank you very much for your help. Now to figure out how to make this work with an http.get, and I'll be set!